# Is there a way to get informed about what app is in the front in runtime in Android?

Tags: android, permissions

For my app I need to generate a list of the applications that the user has used in a period.

Is it possible to receive an event every time an app happens to be in the front?

What permissions are needed? Can be received by normal apps or only by system apps?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use permission "android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" and then get the windows by using List getWindows ();

Read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html

Users have to access the service manually, and are warned when activated.
Activation looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbsB2.png)